# VBA: Why do people include the variable's name in a "Next" statement?

Tags: vba, for-loop, syntax, semantics

I have always written my For-loops like this:

```
For foo = 1 to 10
    ' do something
Next
```

However, when I read code snippets online, people always do this:

```
For foo = 1 to 10
    ' do something
Next foo
```

I have not noticed any difference between the two, and I can't find any documentation on `next` statement is more desirable. What is the difference between those two (if any)?

Comment: Traditionally it was required in all BASIC-derived languages for `For..Next` statements.  That changed later, but many folks (me included) still do it out of habit.  Other folks may do it because they see us older folks doing it and either copy it or assume that it is required.

Comment: +1 @RBarryYoung also, if you happen to have many nested loops it's quite easy to distinguish which loop you're working inside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The counter after the `Next` statement is optional. It used to be required in BASIC-derived languages, but this is no longer the case in VBA.

You can check the [VBA reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251601.aspx):

> If you omit *counter* in a **Next** statement, execution continues as if counter is included. If a **Next** statement is encountered before its corresponding **For** statement, an error occurs.

The reason people still add the counter it to increase readability.

Answer (score 1):

It's for when you have multiple `for` loops.

For example,

```
    For i to j
        For k to l

         next k
     next i
```

Otherwise, the `next` is ambiguous. It's not absolutely necessary, as the loop will still work without it, but it's just good practice to have it marked for the sake of anyone else reading your code.