# how to write a vba code to remove and replace UTF8-Characters

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code and I still can't seem to replace non English characters like Vietnamese or Thai from my data with a simple "placeholder".

```
Sub NonLatin()
Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        s = cell.Value
            For i = 1 To Len(s)
                If Mid(s, i, 1) Like "[!A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&* * ]" Then cell.Value = "placeholder"
            Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: Also wouldn't you need an i and a cell after your NEXT statements?

Comment: Have a look at using `RegEx` instead

Comment: @Luuklag you don't *have to* include the counter variable after the `Next` statement, it's just good practice as it increases readability. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993482/vba-why-do-people-include-the-variables-name-in-a-next-statement)

Comment: @Wilson are you trying to replace the non-English characters with a placeholder, or change the value of the entire cell if it contains a non-English character? You may find [this article](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/howto-convert-vba-unicode-to-utf8.html) useful, which contains code to convert strings to UTF-8 characters and in-fill unknown characters with `?`

Comment: @Wolfie Good to know, still not too old to learn something ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace any chars that are out of e. g. ASCII range (first 128 chars) with placeholder using the below code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim oCell As Range

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[^u0000-u00F7]"
        For Each oCell In [A1:C4]
            oCell.Value = .Replace(oCell.Value, "*")
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

See [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) for details about using Regular Expressions in your VBA code.

---

Then use regular expressions in a function like this one to process strings. Here I am assuming you want to replace each invalid **character** with a placeholder, rather than the entire string. If it's the entire string then you don't need to do individual character checks, you can simply use the `+` or `*` qualifiers for multiple characters in your Regular Expression's pattern, and test the entire string together.

```
Function LatinString(str As String) As String
    ' After including a reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"
    ' Set up the regular expressions object
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        ' This is the pattern of ALLOWED characters. 
        ' Note that special characters should be escaped using a slash e.g. \$ not $
        .Pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9]"
    End With

    ' Loop through characters in string. Replace disallowed characters with "?"
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        If Not regEx.Test(Mid(str, i, 1)) Then
            str = Left(str, i - 1) & "?" & Mid(str, i + 1)
        End If
    Next i
    ' Return output
    LatinString = str
End Function
```

You can use this in your code by

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    cell.Value = LatinString(cell.Value)
Next
```

---

For a byte-level method which converts a Unicode string to a UTF8 string, without using Regular Expressions, check out [this article](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/howto-convert-vba-unicode-to-utf8.html)

Comment: Why not ignore case and use a simpler expression?

Comment: You could well do that @Tom, I was keeping the example as similar as possible to [a simplified version of] the OP's pattern, and the example given in the linked question. It would be even neater to leave out the line I included as `IgnoreCase = False` is the default - I was just showing some options! :)